# Turn File and Print Sharing on with Windows Firewall Off

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a Windows 2008 Server R2 that has a fax server on it. This server is NOT on a domain but WORKGROUP. The server has no firewall. The fax server is used for a critical application.

Problem:
I would like to SHARE the FAX server to a couple users on a domain.

I can go to Control Panel | Hardware | Devices and Printers and try to share the fax, but I get an error (0x000006D9). From [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2123653) I must have the Windows Firewall Service enabled.

- Is there a way to share a printer/fax without the Firewall ON? I can
  try turning the firewall on and then sharing the fax, and then
  turning off the firewall. *But not sure what will happen.*
- Or is there a way to access the fax server remotely without using a
  share?

I can not leave the firewall on. There is way to many applications running on it and other servers connecting remotely and probably turn into a huge headache getting everything running again. Which is why my predecessor left the firewall off and not on the domain with windows updates off for the last 2 years... Egads...

Comment: Like Nathan says below - start the service.  Turn off the firewall itself if you must (in the firewall settings), but keep the service running.

Comment: Wait...no windows updates and the firewall service has been disabled for 2 years?  You sure you even want that server running with network connectivity?

Comment: lead support for the application on this server answer for doing the updates was "Microsoft Updates break things"...... lol

Comment: How many times have we all heard "well, the guy here before me just disabled the firewall because they couldn't get it to work"..  UGH  I have industrial machinery that the techs did the same thing.  In talking to Japan and Germany where this equipment was manufactured, they both said this was SOP.  <face palm>  Windows firewall isn't hard to figure out is it? or maybe its just me and not wanting to leave everything unlocked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you must not have the firewall "on", you can work around this by setting it to allow incoming traffic by default instead of blocking.

Windows Firewall is basically embedded in Windows core networking components and needs to be enabled for a majority of things (sharing, for example) to work properly. Either set it to allow all by default or put in a rule to allow all traffic and bypass the block anyway. Either way, you *must* have it enabled.